# Obstruction and rational points on curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves, brauer-groups

Is etale-Brauer the only obstruction to the existence of rational points on projective plane curves over number fields?

Answer (score 10):

As a supplement to Daniel's answer, I'd like to mention that for (smooth projective geometrically irreducible) curves over number fields, "Brauer-Manin is the only obstruction to the existence of rational points" is a question formulated in Skorobogatov's book (page 133) and a conjecture of mine. See [my paper](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/schrift.html#AG16), in particular sections 8 and 9. The statement is true when the Tate-Shafarevich group and the Mordell-Weil group of the Jacobian are both finite, see Thm. 8.6 in the paper. Poonen in [this paper](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/heuristic.pdf) (Experiment. Math. 2006) has a conjecture based on heuristic considerations that would imply the general statement.

Answer (score 9):

I consider only smooth curves for simplicity. In which case this is expected to be true, but certainly not known in general. In fact, it is even expected that the Brauer-Manin obstruction is already enough. For curves of genus $1$ this would follow from the finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group.

See Section 6.2 of the book

Skorobogatov - Torsors and rational points.